# What "Convolution filters along the time axis" means?

Tags: convolution, tensor

Suppose that I have a tensor of height:25 and width:50. Height is my temporal axis, therefore I have a window of 25 time steps. Therefore my input tensor is:

[image]

I want to extract temporal features / focus on temporal features and therefore use 1d convolution. Please correct me if I am wrong but extracting temporal features signifies applying convolution along temporal axis which results in applying a filter size of height: k and width: 1 (with k is 3 or 5 for example). Which results in

[image]

Extracting one value using different time steps of 1 signal seems logic to me but at the same time I wonder if extracting temporal features means to extract a feature for each time steps therefore:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do either - or both together, however temporal convolution refers to convolving along the time axis.

When using 1D-convolutions, we normally treat the features as channels (so in your example there are 50 channels). When the convolutional filter is constructed, it will have separate weights for each channel, so a filter of size 5 will have $5 \times 50$ weights. Using a single filter and "same" padding gives these results:

[image]

So in this case, each extracted feature contains information that comes from all the channels and the surrounding time steps.

Using 2D-convolutions gives us other options. Here we treat the input as being $25 \times 50$ with a single channel. Using a $n \times 1$ filter gives your first configuration, where each extracted feature comes from surrounding time steps only. (Note: a $1 \times n$ filter gives your second configuration, but does not convolve temporally). The final option is to use an $n \times m$ filter - e.g.:

[image]

Here the extracted features come from the surrounding time steps and surrounding input features. Using this type of filter can be useful if the second dimension is also sequential data (e.g. spectral data).

Comment: Thank you for your explanation but let me correct, in your "Note", there is a typo error, no? "Note: a ×1 filter gives your second configuration, but does not convolve temporally" it should be 1xn instead of nx1? @Lynn

Comment: @MasA - well spotted! Yes it should be $1 \times n$. I've fixed it now. Thanks!

Comment: So, could we say that second configuration (2D-convolution with nx1 filter) does not help us to extract temporal features of input time window? @Lynn

Comment: Correct. The features this type of convolution would extract are not temporal features as they don't have a time dimension. However, depending on the problem being modelled, they could still be useful features.

Comment: It is very clear now, thank you for your effort!